# Apache CXF could not send message to third party webservice connection timeout but works from soapUI when Authorization header is added

Tags: java, cxf, soap-client, webservices-client

Apache CXF could not send message to third party webservice and throws away connection timeout, but it works from soapUI when Authorization header is added.

we have applied few solutions provided in other similar questions, but didn't work. 
- Added Authorization element to the client with encrypted username and password
- Verified the endpoint URL and looks fine

Here is the code used to create soap client

```
    JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
    factory.setAddress(url);
    factory.setUsername(username);
    factory.setPassword(password);
    T client = factory.create(portClass);
    org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client soapClient =       
    ClientProxy.getClient(client);

    HTTPConduit httpConduit = (HTTPConduit) soapClient.getConduit();
    final HTTPClientPolicy policy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
    AuthorizationPolicy authorization = new AuthorizationPolicy();
    authorization.setAuthorization("<encryptedusernamepassword>");
    httpConduit.setAuthorization(authorization);
    httpConduit.setClient(policy);
```

Here is the complete error message:

```
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not send Message.
  at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:64)
  at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:255)
  at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:544)
  at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:341)
  at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:294)
  at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:73)
  at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:124)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
  at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
  at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
  at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
  at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)


Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: ConnectException invoking <url>: Connection timed out: connect
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
  at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.mapException(HTTPConduit.java:2163)
  at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:2148)
  at org.apache.cxf.io.CacheAndWriteOutputStream.postClose(CacheAndWriteOutputStream.java:47)
  at org.apache.cxf.io.CachedOutputStream.close(CachedOutputStream.java:194)
  at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
  at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:733)
  at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
  ... 33 more

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
  at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
  at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:570)
  at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:158)
  at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:411)
  at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:525)
  at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:272)
  at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:329)
  at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:172)
  at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:923)
  at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:158)
  at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1031)
  at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:230)
  at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleHeadersTrustCaching(HTTPConduit.java:2058)
  at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(HTTPConduit.java:2010)
  at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.write(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:42)
  at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractThresholdOutputStream.write(AbstractThresholdOutputStream.java:69)
  at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:2078)
```

**Edit**

This is fixed by adding the proxy url to the client object using HTTPClientPolicy . It might be useful for others.

```
final HTTPClientPolicy policy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
    policy.setProxyServer("<your proxy url>");
    policy.setProxyServerPort(80);
    httpConduit.setClient(policy);
```

Comment: Have you checked the URL?

Comment: Yes, verified the URL and it is fine. We are able to hit the same url from browser successfully. Thanks for your response.
Here is the URL:https://staging.xxx.xxx.com/soap/xxxxxx (sorry have to replace with xxx).

Comment: Strange.Searching the web for `cxf "java.net.ConnectException: ConnectException invoking" "Connection timed out: connect"` shows the actual URL in the error message, not `<url>`.